# Facebook - What is "XD Proxy", and can I block/hide it?

Tags: php, facebook, actionscript-3, proxy, smartfoxserver

I'm trying to integrate a Flash Professional/AS3 game into Facebook.  The swf is hosted on a secure (https) server.  The swf has to connect to a SmartFoxPro socket server on another domain.

I'm using the Facebook Actionscript API to interface with Facebook.  (Should I use PHP, instead?  I read an article that recommends using PHP, because the Actionsrcipt API may not be kept up to date.)  When I fire up my app, I get a "Security Information" pop-up box saying that the page contains both secure and nonsecure items.  I click "yes" to all the display of the nonsecure items.

Then, I get an "XD Proxy blah-blah-blah" popup.  This pop-up goes away, and then my app logs in to my SmartFox server.

So... What is this "XD Proxy" window?  I think it looks unprofessional, and users may think there's an error with the app.  Can I block or hide this window?

Also, can I block or hide the "Security Information" pop-up?  Why don't I see this in other FB apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With regard to XD Proxy:

http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/InternetExplorer/thread/fac1a0b0-fd15-482c-987c-57eba4c95c36

> ...When I fire up my app, I get a "Security Information" pop-up box saying that the page contains both secure and nonsecure items. I click "yes" to all the display of the nonsecure items.

The reason you are seeing this is because there are some elements on your page going through SSL and others that are not. Check to make sure the elements in your app are going through https:// (This includes images, links to CSS and JS files, links to SWF files, etc). I'm not sure about whether you need to have your flash element connect to your SmartFox server in a secure method, but if you can it would be a bonus.

Comment: Regarding "Security Information" - I'm loading some elements (SWFs, images, etc) through relagive URLs.  For example: URLRequest("assets/myFile.swf").  How can I force that to go through https?  Do I need to include the full path?  That will be a pain when I switch between testing on localhost vs my server.

Comment: I'm not certain, but you may be able to use a cross domain policy to specify that it should use https. Check the Adobe documentation for more information.